# extracted pdf page and pdf files are not uploaded for some of the pdf files

Tags: php, mysql, imagemagick, wampserver, ghostscript

I use imagemagic/ghostscript with my script below to extract the first page of a pdf file and convert it to jpg format , i then use an html form to upload the the jpg picture along with the pdf file and other information into my wamp server.
but to my suprise, it upload some pdf files and goes to the confirmation page which is only activated when upload is successful. but for some, it returns the $err message. can you please hep me out?

```
<?php include ('head.php');
    include ('connect.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


        $pdfDirectory = "pdf/";
        $thumbDirectory = "pdfimage/";

        //get the name of the file
        $filename = basename( $_FILES['pdf']['name'], ".pdf");

        //remove all characters from the file name other than letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores
        $filename = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/", "", $filename).".pdf";

        //name the thumbnail image the same as the pdf file
        $thumb = basename($filename, ".pdf");


                $title=$_POST['title'] ;
                $author= $_POST['author'] ; 
                $pub = $_POST['pub'];               
                $abstract= $_POST['abstract'] ;
                $year= $_POST['year'] ;
                $category= $_POST['cat'] ;  




                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $pdfDirectory.$filename)){

                        //the path to the PDF file
                        $pdfWithPath = $pdfDirectory.$filename;

                         //add the desired extension to the thumbnail
                        $thumb = $thumb.".jpg";

                        //execute imageMagick's 'convert', setting the color space to RGB and size to 200px wide
                        exec("convert \"{$pdfWithPath}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -background white -geometry 200 -flatten $thumbDirectory$thumb");

                        //show the image
                        //echo "<p><a href=\"$pdfWithPath\"><img src=\"pdfimage/$thumb\" alt=\"\" /></a></p>";

                        $imagez = "pdfimage/$thumb";

                        $query ="INSERT INTO books (title, author, publisher, abstract, year, category, book, bkimage) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$author."', '".$pub."', '".$abstract."', '".$year."', '".$category."', '".$filename."', '".$imagez."')" ;

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$result) {
            $err = "Could not Add to library at this time";
        } else {
            header('Location:confirm.php');

            }
                    }
        }

 ?>
```

#### Add Books to the Library

Title
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Author
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Publisher
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Abstract
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Year
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Category
                                    
                                  Select...
                                  Architecture
                                  Building Engineering
                                  Civil Engineering
                                  Computer
                                  Electrical Engineering
                                  Land Survey
                                  General Management
                                  Mechanical Engineering
                                  Quantity Survey
                                  Others
                                
                                
                                    Upload Book

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$err = "Could not Add to library at this time";
```

do something like this:

```
$err = "Could not Add to library at this time. SQL: ".$query;
```

If you are not able to see where the problem is, connect to mysql and run the query. You should be able to see mysql error (which I was asking for in the first answer =)).

Comment: i got it through thorough debugging, i guessed since the script was working for some of the .pdf file already, the problem was not from the script but the file. So i discovered some of the files are larger than what could be processed. So i adjusted my upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in the php.ini file. And they worked. thank you all

Comment: Cool thing you got it working! I thought that could be the problem and I thought you could be able to see that sql is trying to insert empty $filename (but wasn't sure which thing triggered error).